# How to get email from pop.gmail.com using c#?

Tags: c#

i want to read email from pop.gmail.com using console application.

```
Pop3 client = new Pop3();
client.Connect("pop.gmail.com",995);
client.Login("xyz@searce.com", "12345");
//client.IsAuthenticated = true; 

// get message list 
Pop3MessageCollection list = client.GetMessageList();

if (list.Count == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("There are no messages in the mailbox.");
}
else 
{
    // download the first message 
    MailMessage message = client.GetMailMessage(list[0].SequenceNumber);

}


client.Disconnect();

        }
```

i got error server has closed the connection.
i have already disable firewall and antivirus.

plz help me.

Comment: I wasn't aware that .NET came with a pop3 client. I ended up implementing my own over .NET TCP. That way I could see all the errors. Shouldn't you normally first query the server for the capabilities? Perhaps you are using the wrong authentication, or something. It may be better to ask your question on the mailing list for the library you are using.

Comment: what is Pop3 ?? is it thrid party library

Answer (score 2):

You need to connect using SSL. I'm not sure which third-party library you're using (there are dozens, and I imagine at least more than one that uses the class name `Pop3`), but you might need to set that explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

According to Gmail, you first need to enable POP. Maybe [this](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13273) will help.